# Por que subtrai -48 de um char ele vira inteiro?

Tags: c, char

Vi em outro fórum que o cara subtraiu -48 de um `char` e o `char` passou a ser um inteiro, pô que isso aconteceu?

```
#include<stdio.h>
  int main(){
  char num='3';
  printf("%d",num-48);
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: O tipo char já é um inteiro, geralmente de 8 bits de tamanho; se é 'signed char' ou 'unsigned char', depende da arquitetura. Como a linguagem C tem promoção automática, %d espera um inteiro de tipo 'int' mas pode aceitar short int e char.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Chars na verdade são inteiros, que são um código da tabela [ASCII](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII), então se você subtrai um número dele, vc altera o valor do seu código.

por exemplo:

```
#include<stdio.h>
  int main(){
  char num='3';
  printf("%d",num-48);
  return 0;
}
```

imprimiria o número ***3***, pois o valor do caractere `'3'` é 51 na tabela ASCII, e 51-48 = 3.

você pode fazer esse "macete" tanto para números como para caracteres do alfabeto:

```
//imprime: a b c, d e f
printf("%c %c %c, %c %c %c", 'a', 'a'+ 1, 'a'+ 2, 'f'-2, 'f'-1, 102);
//imprime 0, 0
printf("%d, %d", 'a'- 97, 'A'- 65);
/imprime 47
printf("%d%d",'4'- 48, '7'- 48);
```

para isso basta usar o valor do primeiro "elemento" do conjunto da tabela que vc quer, ou qualquer outro que deseja usar, como base / ponto de referência.

Comment: Só uma observação: Não são necessariamente da tabela ASCII, apesar de ser uma das mais comuns.

Answer (score 6):

Ele não vira inteiro, ou tudo é um inteiro. Este código não mostra que virou um inteiro.

C é uma linguagem de tipagem fraca, por isso todos os valores podem ser interpretados como melhor lhe convier. O código manda interpretar o valor constante na variável `num` como se fosse um tipo decimal inteiro, isto está determinado pelo `%d`, se usar um `%c` estará mandando imprimir a representação deste número como caractere.

O número armazenado existe por si só, você pode dar várias representações textuais para ele sob demanda.

Este código demonstra melhor o que acontece:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {
    char num = '3';
    printf("|%c|%d|%c|%d|", num - 48, num - 48, num, num);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/wCfiKv). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/quayuulq-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Typing/CharNumber.c).